# Como salvar o pdf gerado pelo reportviewer em disco em tempo de execução?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

Estou fazendo uma série de relatórios os quais preciso gerar o PDF e salvar no servidor, para que o usuário faça o download. Não posso utilizar o modo `atatchment` e nem `inline`. Pois o usuário tem a opção de criar vários relatórios e fazer o download depois.

Segue o trecho da conversão:

```
Warning[] warnings;

                string[] streamids;

                string mimeType;

                string encoding;

                string extension;



                string deviceInfo =

                  "<DeviceInfo>" +

                  "  <OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat>" +

                  "  <PageWidth>21cm</PageWidth>" +

                  "  <PageHeight>29.7cm</PageHeight>" +

                  "  <MarginTop>0.1in</MarginTop>" +

                  "  <MarginLeft>0in</MarginLeft>" +

                  "  <MarginRight>0in</MarginRight>" +

                  "  <MarginBottom>0.1in</MarginBottom>" +

                  "</DeviceInfo>";


                byte[] bytes = ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Render("PDF", deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);



                HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();

                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = mimeType;

               // HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "C:\\ExportedReport." + "PDF");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", ("atatchment; filename=ExportedReport." + "PDF"));

                HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();

                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o método [File.WriteAllBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx) no byte array resultante do método `Render`:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\ExportedReport.PDF", bytes);
```

Você irá precisar usar uma lógica para criar nomes diferentes para os arquivos PDF's e armazená-los de alguma maneira para permitir ao usuário baixar depois, podendo usar o método `HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile("C:\\ExportedReport.PDF");` para isso.

Comment: Não deu certo. Eu adicionei essa linha abaixo da linha :                
byte[] bytes = ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Render("PDF",

Comment: Agora está dando o erro:{"Access to the path 'C:\\ExportedReport.PDF' is denied."}. se fosse um arquivo Txt eu teria que criá-lo, como é um pdf , n sei o que fazer

Comment: Provavelmente o usuário utilizado pelo IIS ou IIS Express não tem permissão para gravar em `C:`. Se for IIS, crie uma pasta sob `C:` e de permissão para o usuário *IIS_IUSRS*